# Error while creating a superuser on heroku with django

Tags: python, django, heroku

I've created an app,called learning logs, on heroku (it is an project from the book python crash course).When I try to create a superuser it shows me an error.

I first run (in a termial):

```
heroku run bash
```

and then :

```
python manage.py createsuperuser
```

the main error is the following:

```
You have 20 unapplied migration(s). Your project may not work properly until you apply the migrations for app(s): admin, auth, contenttypes, learning_logs, sessions.
Run 'python manage.py migrate' to apply them.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 383, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: auth_user

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

I have applied the migrations several times but I still get unapplied migrations error.

the rest of the error is this:

```
    File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/commands/createsuperuser.py", line 61, in execute
    return super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 364, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/commands/createsuperuser.py", line 82, in handle
    default_username = get_default_username()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/__init__.py", line 140, in get_default_username
    auth_app.User._default_manager.get(username=default_username)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 402, in get
    num = len(clone)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 256, in __len__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1242, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 55, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1100, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 99, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 67, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 76, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
```

I also get an error while executing the command:

```
git push heroku master
```

and when I run it I get:

```
    Enumerating objects: 18, done.
Counting objects: 100% (18/18), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (12/12), done.
Writing objects: 100% (12/12), 1022 bytes | 511.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 12 (delta 10), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote: -----> Installing requirements with pip
remote:
remote: -----> $ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
```

followed by the error:

```
    remote:        Traceback (most recent call last):
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 20, in <module>
remote:            import psycopg2 as Database
remote:        ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psycopg2'
remote:        During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
remote:        Traceback (most recent call last):
remote:          File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
remote:            main()
remote:          File "manage.py", line 17, in main
remote:            execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
remote:            utility.execute()
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 357, in execute
remote:            django.setup()
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
remote:            apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 114, in populate
remote:            app_config.import_models()
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 211, in import_models
remote:            self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
remote:            return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
remote:          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
remote:          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
remote:          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
remote:          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
remote:          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
remote:          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 2, in <module>
remote:            from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 47, in <module>
remote:            class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 117, in __new__
remote:            new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 321, in add_to_class
remote:            value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 204, in contribute_to_class
remote:            self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 28, in __getattr__
remote:            return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 201, in __getitem__
remote:            backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 110, in load_backend
remote:            return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
remote:            return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 24, in <module>
remote:            raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading psycopg2 module: %s" % e)
remote:        django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading psycopg2 module: No module named 'psycopg2'
remote:
remote:  !     Error while running '$ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput'.
remote:        See traceback above for details.
remote:
remote:        You may need to update application code to resolve this error.
remote:        Or, you can disable collectstatic for this application:
remote:
remote:           $ heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1
remote:
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to blooming-taiga-32833.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/blooming-taiga-32833.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/blooming-taiga-32833.git'
```

Could anyone help me with this problem?

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: I guess that you are using sqlite as your database. You cannot use sqlite on Heroku.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution with the help of the book's writter.
I had to include psycopg2>=2.6.1 to the requirements.txt file.